# How to transform a mesh?

Tags: java, 3d, blender, libgdx

I am very new to developing applications with LibGDX and 3D apps in general and I would just like to know how to move around a 3D object that I imported from blender. I have checked the Mesh class for a transform method but I can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving objects around in 3D is normally done by manipulating a transformation matrix. LibGDX doesn't seem to be open source anymore (for 1 day - April 1st ;P)  so I can't tell you how to do it there but I guess the mesh class isn't the right place to look for. Meshes normally only represent a shape/mesh without any position. You'd often create an object/entity and assign a mesh to it. Then you change the transformation of that entity.

As I said, transforming entities is often either done by calling some move/scale/rotate methods or by creating a transformation matrix yourself and loading it into the graphics pipeline. Modern 3D graphics applications normally use the shaders for that and just load the transformation matrix into the shader pipeline.

Comment: I am pretty sure the source is still available here http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fgdx%2Fsrc%253Fstate%253Dclosed (the official repo) and to render I just have to call the render method from the mesh object.

Comment: Ah I get it, there is Gdx.gl.pop and push matrix and then you can transform it :)

Comment: @notrodash as for LibGDX ceasing to be open source: it was April 1st :)